# Not receiving expanded quota for Google Workspace account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, google-workspace

I believe that I'm not receiving a larger quota with my Google Workspace account. I reached my daily email quota on my regular gmail account.

I copied the google sheet; I renamed the function and file; I ran the script on my Google Workspace account. When I changed the script name, code, and associated email I was *still* unable to run it because `Error: Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email`.

See quota's here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: I believe that it must be detecting the same IP address because I think the exception is being sent from the email service (Gmail) to my IP associated with google script

Comment: I changed my device, recipient email, IP - no progress

Comment: How long have you had your new account?

Comment: I've has the account for 2 months. Ruben found that the issue is total expenditure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you missed this note from the [quota's link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) in the question:

> **Note:** Additional limits apply for trial accounts. After you convert from a free trial account to a paid subscription, your account limits automatically increase when both of the following are true:
>
> - Your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD $100 (or equivalent).
> - At least 60 days have passed since reaching that payment threshold.

Comment: Thank you Rubén. This seem to be my issue because my account is only 60 days old and I've only paid $24 cumulatively.